# how to Initialize a Javascript Array with non-zero index

Tags: javascript

I'm passing an array to a function and I'm curious if there is a quick way to use the json style array initializer to pass an anonymous array:

e.g.:

```
myfunction([1,2,3,4]);
```

Is there some special syntax in javascript that would allow one to initialize the array with non-zero index?

for example, instead of

```
myfunction([,,,,4321]);

//array[4] == 4321 here
```

but if you have an array that has the first 100 positions undefined, you would have to have  100 commas.  [,,....,4321]

basically looking for a short form for:

```
var a = new Array(); a[100] = 4321;
```

that you can use as a function parameter.

Comment: Couldn't you build a loop to pad the array?

Comment: @j08691 not sure how one can loop an anonymous array.  it'd be easier to define the variable upfront which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like:

```
var a = new Array(100).concat([4321]);
```

Comment: Nice.  this should work for more than one entry as well: myfunction(new Array(100).concat([4321], new Array(20), [65433], new Array(999), [234], ...));

Answer (score 3):

Probably shortest approach (but very unreadable) would be

```
(a = [])[100] = 4321;
```

But still you can't use that directly as a function parameter, as it returns the added element, and not the entire array. You still have to call as `myFunction(a)`.

Answer (score 3):

Pass in something like this:

```
myfunction({100: "foo", 101: "bar"});
```

This works:

```
function testArray(arr) {
    alert(arr[4]);
}

testArray({4: "foo"}); //alerts "foo"
```